# Smart Contract overview ERC-20 instead of ERC-721

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, erc-721

I have created ERC-721 standard but on etherscan (Ropsten) it's still showing ERC-20 standard in overview
Below are my contract code, please share your thought if I'm doing something wrong.

```
contract ERC721Token {

 function name() external view returns (string memory);
   function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
   function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
   function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint balance);
   // Functions that define ownership
   function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external returns (address owner);
   function approve(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external returns (bool success); 
   function takeOwnership(uint256 _tokenId) external returns (bool success); 
   function transfer(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external returns (bool success); 
   function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address _owner, uint256 _index) external returns (uint tokenId);
   // Token metadata
   function tokenMetadata(uint256 _tokenId) external returns (string memory infoUrl);
   // Events
   event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _tokenId);
   event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _approved, uint256 _tokenId);
}

contract TestToken is ERC721Token {

  string  public name;
  string  public symbol;
  uint8   public decimals;
  uint256 public totalTokens;
   mapping(address => uint) private balances;
   mapping(uint256 => address) private tokenOwners;
   mapping(uint256 => bool) private tokenExists;
   mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) private allowed;
   mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) private ownerTokens;

  constructor(
        uint256 _totalTokens,
        string memory _tokenName,
        uint8 _decimalsPoints,
        string memory _tokenSymbol
        ) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _totalTokens;
        symbol = _tokenSymbol;
        name = _tokenName;
        decimals = _decimalsPoints;
        totalTokens = 100000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalTokens);
    }



   function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256){
       return totalTokens;
   }
   function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint){
       return balances[_owner];
   }
   function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) public returns (address){
       require(tokenExists[_tokenId]);
       return tokenOwners[_tokenId];
   }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[_to] += _value;
    balances[_from] -= _value;
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function takeOwnership(uint256 _tokenId) public returns(bool success){
      require(tokenExists[_tokenId]);
      return true;
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]);
    //require(_to != 0x0);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }
  function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address _owner, uint256 _index) public returns (uint _tokenId) {
      return 5;
  }
  function tokenMetadata(uint256 _tokenId) public returns (string memory infoUrl) {
     require(tokenExists[_tokenId]);
     return "ss";
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is the document you need to read to properly implement ERC-721 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721.

Answer (score 1):

This is not erc721 standard this is erc20 standard function. For the etherscan to recognise your contract as erc72 your contract interface must implement the erc721 contract standard: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md. I don't see your safeTransfer function or ApprovalForAll event.

The etherscan recognises your contract as erc20 because in your interface you implemented erc20 standard: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20

Comment: I changed as per erc721.org it's working but now the token balance is not transfer into the token owner's account, while deploying contract. m using this in constructor(){

`  emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), totalTokens)   `

}

Comment: @heartbeat i think u should ask that on another question about this because this is not relevent to the question. it Is ok to ask many question but create seperate question each please i can’t read the code in the comment and i don’t understand the issue. So create a separate question maybe i will see if i can help. And btw add more detail the bug what did you do, what have you try and the code

Comment: all right, will do